# How to jQuery in Javascript Timer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I'm trying to create a 'cheat' code for a javascript/html game. By default, this happens:

```
self.begin = function()
{
  self.timer = new Timer(self);
  self.timer.total = Math.round(self.game.text.length*8.75);
```

I want to be able to add something to the end of the URL like this

```
www.example.com/?timerx=20
```

and it change the "8.75" to "20". If no number is given in the URL it will default to the original 8.75.

Comment: So read the querystring value

Answer (score 0):

Just access the query string as follows:

```
var queryString = window.location.search;
```

You will have to parse the query string for timerx to get the decimal value.  Make sure to check to null and empty results.